# Azure cost management access mystery

Tags: azureportal, azure-billing-api, cost-management

I am struggling to get the right access to Cost Management in Azure. I was provided billing reader access. But all we see is no access messages. What exactly is the purpose of billing reader?

In the Cost Management + Billing - Overview, I see subscriptions listed. but cost ('current cost') is given as 'Unauthorized'. So a billing reader can see bills but no cost? Is that another naming gone wrong for Microsoft?

Comment: Is this an Enterprise Agreement (EA) subscription? There's a "view charges" setting on the billing account (enrollment) which disables costs for account owners and RBAC users. If that's disabled, all RBAC users will see unauthorized. Try opening cost analysis from the subscription blade. That should give more explicit messaging. If you can see costs from there, then unauthorized is a bug. Let me know what you see. I can chase this down for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All except EA customers can grant access to Azure billing information by assigning one of the following user roles to members of your team:

Account Administrator
Service Administrator
Co-administrator
Owner
Contributor
Reader
Billing Reader

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-manage-access

Note: You may have access to billing but not to the subscription. OR You don't have access to any subscription in the directory you've selected. So, switch to the right directory with a proper subscription you've access to.

For Cost Management: If you're an EA user, you need combination of permissions granted in the Azure portal and in the EA portal. These permissions are again defined basis scopes. For more details see this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/assign-access-acm-data

Comment: I get the error 'Customer does not have the privilege to see the cost' even though our CSP have assigned me as a Cost Management Contributor and Cost Management Reader at both Subscription and Management Group scope. Our plan is 'Azure plan' and we use a CSP company to provide our Azure services.